# How to extend or override CP template?

Tags: craft3, templating, control-panel

I need to add some custom condition to the top siteMenu selector.

Template file with top menu:

> vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_elements/sitemenu.twig

Block with this menu:

> vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_layouts/elementindex.twig

How can I extend `elementindex.twig` to use my own template from module or override `sitemenu.twig` without changing any of the vendor files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see how this can be done easily(without changing vendor files), mainly because there is no [CP template hook](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/template-hooks.html#control-panel-template-hooks) for such case.

But what you can try to do instead is:

1. [Register JS file(s)](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/asset-bundles.html) for the CP part of website and modify DOM elements as needed via JavaScript.
2. Use EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER_TEMPLATE and modify variables, of course, if it'll be useful in your case

...

```
use yii\base\Event;

use craft\events\TemplateEvent;

use craft\web\View;

...


Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER_TEMPLATE,
    function (TemplateEvent $event) {
        if ($event->templateMode === 'cp' && $event->template === '_layouts/_elements/sitemenu.twig') {
            $variables = $event->variables;
            $variables['groups'] = ...;
            $event->variables = $variables;
        }
        // ...
    }
);
```

Perhaps you can provide more context so the community can help you find a more elegant solution.

Comment: I need just remove all non-English sites from this list.